# How to convert a hex string to base64 for image saving in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, image, file, base64, hex

I'm making a NodeJS sockets.io multiplayer drawing canvas. The data gets saved as color id's in a 2D matrix, and I have an array of color hex codes to match with the id's.

I need to be able to save the image as a file, and so I got to the point of storing the image data as a continuous string, joining every pixel's hex code:

```
// 'boardData' contains the index of the color for each pixel
// 'colors' is an array on hex values

var hexString = ""

for (var x = 0; x < boardWidth; x++) {
    for (var y = 0; y < boardHeight; y++) {
        hexString += colors[boardData[x][y]].replace('#','');
    }
}
```

The result is something like `ffffff3fbae52dffba...`

I managed to convert this string into base64 by doing the following:

```
var base64Data = Buffer.from(hexString, 'hex').toString('base64')
```

Then, I tried saving it by doing this:

```
fs.writeFile("image.png", base64Data, {encoding: 'base64'}, function(err) {
    if (err) return err;
    console.log('Saved!');
});
```

But the resulting images seem to have an incompatible format.

When I try saving a 16x16 completely white image, the base64 code comes out as `///////////////////////////...`, but when I try online image converters, a 16x16 white image becomes `iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAg...`, and hardcoding this into the fs.writeFile data works just fine. Actually, seems like even a 1x1 white image yields a lot of characters, so I'm not entirely sure how this even works.

I believe I'm missing a step here. Can someone point me in the right direction? Is there maybe another way of converting this raw color data into an image file?

Comment: I think var base64Data = Buffer.from(hexString, 'hex').toString('base64') is not returning the right base64Data. Log it via console.log(base64Data,"base64Data").

Comment: When i console.log base64Data for a completely white image, it shows //////////////... if i add an ocational black pixel it reads ///////////AAAA/////... . This is the result you get for just transforming hex into base64, but im pretty sure that for it to be in image format, it has to include more information.

Comment: If i turn the hex "ffffff" into base64, it becomes "////". This would be the result of me transforming a 1x1 white pixel into base64. But when i input a 1x1 white pixel image into an online encoder, it returns quite a long string. It seems to me that this is not the correct process to transform into a usable format.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution. This library called Jimp does exactly what i was looking for.

For anyone that wants to know. just had to install the module by openning up a command terminal, navigating to my nodejs server folder and running this:

```
npm install --save jimp
```

Then, on my server code, i have to import this library (Note that it has to be uppercase J):

```
var Jimp = require('jimp')
```

And so i just do this to save the image:

```
let jimg = new Jimp(boardWidth, boardHeight);
for (var x=0; x<boardWidth; x++) {
    for (var y=0; y<boardHeight; y++) {
        var hex = colors[boardData[x][y]].replace('#','');
        var num = parseInt(hex+"ff", 16);
        jimg.setPixelColor(num, x, y);
    }
}
jimg.write("output.png")
```

Hope this helps someone!